# group by CASE in SQL Server/SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

in Sqlalchemy (0.8.2) I am trying to *SELECT CASE GROUP BY CASE* 
something like that:

```
query = """
     SELECT count([HR_PERSONNEL].[S_HR_PERSONNEL_ID]) AS value, 
       CASE 
         WHEN (floor(datediff(day, [HR_PERSONNEL].[D_DATE_OF_BIRTH], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) / 365.25) < 15) THEN 15 
         WHEN (floor(datediff(day, [HR_PERSONNEL].[D_DATE_OF_BIRTH], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) / 365.25) BETWEEN 15 AND 19) THEN 19
         ELSE 100 END AS anon_1 
      FROM [HR_PERSONNEL] 
      GROUP BY CASE 
        WHEN (floor(datediff(day, [HR_PERSONNEL].[D_DATE_OF_BIRTH], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) / 365.25) < 15) THEN 15 
        WHEN (floor(datediff(day, [HR_PERSONNEL].[D_DATE_OF_BIRTH], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) / 365.25) BETWEEN 15 AND 19) THEN 19 
        ELSE 100 END"""
```

the plain text SQL query can be executed with SA without a problem:

```
>>> for i in mssql_engine.execute(query):
        print i

(11, 15)
(1097, 19)
(63878, 100)
```

but I have a problem with the same query in SQLAlchemy ORM:

```
>>> age_case_groups =case([( floor_function  < 15, 15)\
                                ,(between(floor_function,15,19), 19)],else_=100)
>>> vols_by_age = session.query(func.count(HrPersonnel.S_HR_PERSONNEL_ID).label('value'),age_case_groups)\
                .group_by(age_case_groups)
>>> vols_by_age.all()

 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#43>", line 1, in <module>
        vols_by_age.all()
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2104, in all
        return list(self)
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2216, in __iter__
        return self._execute_and_instances(context)
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2231, in _execute_and_instances
        result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 662, in execute
        params)
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 761, in _execute_clauseelement
        compiled_sql, distilled_params
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 874, in _execute_context
        context)
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1024, in _handle_dbapi_exception
        exc_info
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 163, in raise_from_cause
        reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 867, in _execute_context
        context)
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 324, in do_execute
        cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
```

> ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Column
>   'HR_PERSONNEL.D_DATE_OF_BIRTH' is invalid in the select list because
>   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause. (8120) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Column 'HR_PERSONNEL.D_DATE_OF_BIRTH' is invalid in
>   the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause. (8120); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]Column 'HR_PERSONNEL.D_DATE_OF_BIRTH' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. (8120); [42000]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not
>   be prepared. (8180)") u'SELECT
>   count([HR_PERSONNEL].[S_HR_PERSONNEL_ID]) AS value, CASE WHEN
>   (floor(datediff(day, [HR_PERSONNEL].[D_DATE_OF_BIRTH],
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) / ?) < ?) THEN ? WHEN (floor(datediff(day,
>   [HR_PERSONNEL].[D_DATE_OF_BIRTH], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) / ?) BETWEEN ?
>   AND ?) THEN ? ELSE ? END AS anon_1 \nFROM [HR_PERSONNEL] GROUP BY CASE
>   WHEN (floor(datediff(day, [HR_PERSONNEL].[D_DATE_OF_BIRTH],
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) / ?) < ?) THEN ? WHEN (floor(datediff(day,
>   [HR_PERSONNEL].[D_DATE_OF_BIRTH], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) / ?) BETWEEN ?
>   AND ?) THEN ? ELSE ? END' (365.25, 15, 15, 365.25, 15, 19, 19, 100,
>   365.25, 15, 15, 365.25, 15, 19, 19, 100)

looks like MSSQL/ODBC bug???

Comment: Have you verified that the query is working without SQLAlchemy? Because I cannot spot any differences between your query above and the error below. And if it does **not** work outside of SQLAlchemy, i.e. speaking directly with the DB server, then your problem is not with SQLAlchemy.

Comment: SQL query works fine outside SQLAlchemy

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: nope, i just used a plain sql for that

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, just a result of the way pyodbc works: it uses actual prepared statements (instead of inlining the params in Python), and so when preparing the query SQL Server cannot know what the parameters will be, which means that `x + ?` in a SELECT list is not necessarily the same as `x + ?` in a GROUP BY.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Raw query is working fine. But if I run through SQLAlchemy then its throwing the error

Comment: i moved the database to Oracle and SqlAlchemy ORM query works there. it must be something with pyodbc
    ora_age_func = func.floor(...)

    age_case_groups = case(
        [
            ( between(ora_age_func, 15, 19), '15-19' ),
...
        ], else_='?'
    )

    vols_by_age = session_oms.query(
                func.count(),
                age_case_groups
            )....
            .group_by( age_case_groups)