# SQLAlchemy escape/sanitize variables without using ORM/parameters

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Does SQLAlchemy provide a function to safely quote/escape a literal when constructing raw queries? I've read through the docs and have seen nothing, not sure if it is a protected internal?

I am aware parameterized statements are the correct way to handle this, but due to a [fringe case/bug with pyodbc/mssql-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307466/group-by-case-in-sql-server-sqlalchemy) this is not an option. As a result I am forced to execute a compiled ORM statement with `literal_binds=True`. Worst case scenario I would just limit the input to A-Z|0-9 or get creative with chained subqueries/aliases but I would prefer to avoid this.

e.g.

```
variable = sqlalchemy.escape_text(input("User Input")) // something like this
q = session.query(MyObj).filter(MyObj.colA == variable))
connection.execute(q.selectable.compile(compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True}), bind=session.bind)
```

Comment: Also, what's the fringe case/bug that prevents using placeholders / parameterized queries?

Comment: The docs explicitly say that literal_binds should not be used with untrusted input: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/sqlexpressions.html#rendering-bound-parameters-inline - what i'm looking for is more of a bleach-type-sanitization to not have to worry about sql injection

And the issue is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307466/group-by-case-in-sql-server-sqlalchemy - The query produced by SQLalchemy runs perfectly fine when copy/pasted into the database console

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. As to actual quoting mechanism, I think you'd have to rely on your DB-API driver's tools, if provided.

Comment: Shouldn't this then have mssql and pyodbc as tags... And you could perhaps describe the actual problem too

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the issue in the question you linked in the comments is that pyodbc uses actual prepared statements, and so when preparing SQL Server has no idea what the actual parameters will be (before execution), which means that `foo + ?` in a SELECT list may not be the same as `foo + ?` in the GROUP BY clause. No idea if there's a work around for that in SQL Server; in Postgresql you could use positional placeholders ($1, etc.) to make it known that the parameter is the same.

Comment: Also noteworthy: the big warning about untrusted input has been added in version 1.2 and up. The same info is available before as well, you just have to read the docs more carefully (which I had not done, a lesson learned...).